# How to control terminal of cypress in UI mode

Tags: cypress

When running cypress in UI mode, the terminal is filled up with requests similar to

```
GET /_/ 200 90.700 ms
```

How to stop cypress from printing all these requests to the terminal in the UI mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command to open cypress in UI mode

```bash
cypress open 1>/dev/null
```

and this will keep your terminal empty from all these requests